# neo4j - on relation using randomUUID() property sometimes set with null

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I try to get relationships property before delete them and set a unique identifier if needed.

There are some times the result is the rId (r.uid) is null but the relationship type (rType) is not.

```
MATCH (n:someType { uid: someId } )-[r]-()


SET (
    CASE
    WHEN r.uid IS NULL
    THEN r END ).uid = randomUUID()

WITH r, properties(r) as props, startNode(r).uid as uidFrom, 
endNode(r).uid as uidTo, type(r) as rType,  LABELS(startNode(r)) as 
typeFrom, LABELS(endNode(r)) as typeTo, r.uid as rId

DELETE r

RETURN aidFrom, aidTo, rProps, rType, typeFrom, typeTo, rId
```

If the type is not null, then I have a relationship for sure, but if the r.uid is null then the r.uid is not set.

what I miss here?